# Is sphericity the same as profile?

Tags: drafting, drawings

I have to inspect a sphere on a CMM, and the standard states that the "Sphericity must be within 0.02mm". I am using a Zeiss CMM, and it does not have a 'sphericity' inspection method, but it does have a 'profile' inspection method. Since profile is essentially ensuring a tolerance band that would cover the whole sphere, would this suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could argue that sphericity is a specific type of profile tolerance. You would just need to make sure perfectly opposing points on the surface (or as close to it as possible)  are inspected to properly calculate the diameter.